# running service in background of android app to check for network connection

Tags: android, networking, service

For my app, I would like to have a service running at all times that the app is loaded that will be checking the availability of a network connection, and as soon as it realizes that a network connection is not available, send a message to the loaded activity so that I can replace the content view of that activity with one that simply states "Network Connection is not available".  Then when the network connection comes back, have the activity receive another message so it can switch the content view back.  I've looked through several posts on services, and would just like to inquire as the best way to go about this.  Any tutorials or simple sample code would be awesome too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `Service` for that is not really the best solution. Better is using a `BroadcastReceiver`. You can add one programmatically as shown [here](http://thiranjith.com/2011/03/31/how-to-monitor-network-connectivity-in-android/), or in the manifest like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app).

Comment: Okay, after reading through some posts and tutorials, I'm starting to understand Broadcast Receivers, however many of the examples show registering the receiver within the manifest.  Correct me if I am wrong, but if I do it that way, my code within my broadcast receiver will be triggered even when my application is not running correct?  I want to have the code only run when my app is up and running in the foreground so I can see the change in network status, determine if it's connected or disconnected, and take appropriate action.  Any examples anyone could provide on how to do this?

Comment: I've decided to just check for network issues on a failed HTTP request rather than registering broadcast receivers.  thank you anyways for your help.  Marking as accepted as this method would have worked but is not really necessary for what I need.

Comment: Yea, i guess it depends on the use case. The first method would still work fine. You could register the `BroadcastReceiver` in `onStart()` and unregister it again in `onStop()`