# Failures with Java socket

Tags: java, android, sockets, client

```
    Socket socket = null;
    PrintWriter out =null;
    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName(host);
    socket = new Socket(ip,port);
    out = new PrintWriter( new BufferedWriter( new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())),true);
    out.println(myString);
    if(socket!=null)
        socket.close();
```

My android code is this. I need to save the string in a file if there is any kind of problem (no internet connection, no server avaible, ecc... I tried with a try-catch, but even if there is no internet/server avaible, no exception is thrown. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to believe that the code will not throw an IOException or an UnknownHostException if you try to resolve a hostname with `InetAddress.getByName(host)` without a network being available. Maybe you could post more of your code (with the try-catch-block).

Also I would suggest you try using a DataOutputStream to write your string to the socket:

```
DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
dataOutputStream.writeUTF(myString);
```

Furthermore I would suggest that you check the availability of your internet connection by either listening to the apropriate broadcasts in android or by asking the connection-manager.

```
public static boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable(Context context) {

    boolean isNetworkConnectionAvailable = false;

    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService("connectivity");
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if(activeNetworkInfo != null) 
    {
        isNetworkConnectionAvailable = 
                activeNetworkInfo.getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED;
    }
    return isNetworkConnectionAvailable;
}
```

Or see here: [broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app).

Comment: Ok, in this way i know if i'm connected, but if i'm connected but the server is not reachable, i need to save the string in a file. I saw that  `InetAddress.isReachable()` is not reliable.

Comment: The solution to your problem is not to rely on the fact that something has been transfered to another host just because there was no exception. I would strongly suggest that you send an acknowledgment back from the server to the client. If there is no such acknowledgement after a certain time (read timeout) then you should write the string to a file. Look up books on protocol design maybe.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method, [InetAddress.isReachable](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isReachable%28int%29), to check if you can ping the host. There's no direct method to check internet connectivity

usage (no try/catch)-

```
    if(ip.isReachable(3000)) // timeout is 3000 ms ie 3s
    {
           // internet available,do something
    }
```

Comment: So i have just to use that method in the try-catch? I'll try thank you.

Comment: I tried it, but now, even if the server is online, i can't connect to it (i'm using avd and a server in my pc, so if i remove the if the connection works correctly). So i guess if i use a server like that the ip is not reachable.

Comment: Try increasing the timeout to 10000 (10 secs).

Comment: Still nothing. I read that `InetAddress.isReachable()` is not reliable. Are there any alternative way?