# error : BroadcastReceiver trying to return result

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am trying to understand when device is connected to internet.

but I get this error :

```
03-12 20:35:06.801: E/BroadcastReceiver(28892): BroadcastReceiver trying to return result during a non-ordered broadcast
```

---

My BroadcastReceiver  :

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


    // Explicitly specify that which service class will handle the intent.
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            YourService.class.getName());

    intent.putExtra("isNetworkConnected",isConnected(context));
    context.startService((intent.setComponent(comp)));


    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}

public  boolean isConnected(Context context) {
       ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
       NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
       return networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isAvailable() && networkInfo.isConnected();
 }

}
```

---

My service :

```
public class YourService extends IntentService{

public YourService() {
    super("Test");
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
  Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
  boolean isNetworkConnected = extras.getBoolean("isNetworkConnected");
  // your code
  if(isNetworkConnected){
      Log.e("TAG", "Yes");
  }

}

}
```

---

My manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.ex80"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.ex80.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
<receiver android:name=".ConnectivityChangeReceiver" >
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>        
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: consider Gabe Sechan answer and remove the `setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);`. You can not set result to broadcast that are unordered. i.e. to broadcasts that are not sent through `context.sendOrderedBroadcast()`...

Comment: I changed my code to : paste.ubuntu.com/7080866 . but I have not any LOG : Log.e("TAG", "Yes");

Answer (score 0):

Your onRecieve is altering the intent and trying to use it to start a service.  You should use a new intent to start the service instead.

Comment: I changed my code to : http://paste.ubuntu.com/7080866/ . but I have not any LOG : Log.e("TAG", "Yes");