# How to create a service in android to start when user is connected with internet

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

In my application, I want to start a `service` when user is connected with the internet using `manifest` declaration but in `android` documentation connectivity `broadcast` can only be registered inside a component. For that app should be running state. But I want to start the `service` to show `notification` independent of app state (running, paused, destroyed etc).
Simply I want to implement Gmail notification functionality in my app like Gmail shows notification when user is connected to internet independent of Gmail app state.Thanks!!

Comment: here is complete solution have look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22310691/5110595)

Comment: Most likely, Gmail is using FCM (or something derived from that), not some service that runs in response to Internet connectivity.

Comment: @CommonsWare I alsowant to use FCM but to convert fcm message in notification we need to build notification in some service right

Comment: You can raise a `Notification` from any `Context`. Gmail probably does this from [a service started by FCM](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive), as Gmail has other work to do that takes time (e.g., downloading the email messages and writing them to disk).

Comment: @CommonsWare Actually i want to listen for <code>childAdded()</code> callback from real time database provided by firebase in background.

Answer (score 1):

For anything you would want your application to do when it's not running, it has to be in a background service. You can implement a continuous check for the internet connectivity in that service.

Extend FirebaseMessagingService with your custom logic to listen to any FCM notification.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/FirebaseMessagingService

Comment: I want to use FCM service.

Comment: Extend FirebaseMessagingService with your custom logic to listen to any FCM notification. This service would continue to run even when your application is closed and would react to any FCM notification according to your custom logic.

Comment: And if I have to listen on real time database change..then

Comment: So we have to start activity in some component right? So for this that component should be in running state

Comment: If you're talking about the database changes on your server, you would need to identify those changes and send FCM notification to your application from your backend about those changes.

Comment: The component should run once to kick-start this background service and then can be closed. Your custom background service would keep running.

Comment: Yeah but without using any component how can I start service. Is there any way.

Comment: No. This is your application-specific service and application should run at least once to kick-start this service. At best, You can have this service started in the first application activity itself. No other way.