# how can I set a broadcast receiver receives only once while changing the internet connection

Tags: android

I am new in android. I want to set up a broadcast receiver which receives only once when the internet connection is changed. I have set up one but it receives at least 3 times. Could any one please help me.

in androidmainfest.xml

```
  <receiver android:name=".NetworkServices" >
            <intent-filter >
                <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

public class NetworkServices extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       ConnectionDetector cd = new ConnectionDetector(context);
       Boolean isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
        if(isInternetPresent){          
            new DoAsyncTask().execute(context);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: there are many way, but what you want to do?: 1) check internet connection once 2) handle changes in Network state?

Comment: could you please point me one solution

Comment: I want to call a custom service while the internet connection is established once in a day

Comment: Show the code you tried, where you receive it 3 times. Especially how you register the receiver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first case:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
and check (e.g.):
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI)
            if(activeNetwork.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE)
```

In the second case you can register a receiver for system wide network change event as described here: [Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)
after that if you do not want to receive anymore you can use something like:

```
 PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
   ComponentName compName = 
        new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), 
            ConnectivityChangeReceiver.class);
   pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(
        compName,
        PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, 
        PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

But only once. 
If you need to do every day you must use alarm manager and android service.

Answer (score 0):

I think u misunderstanding the meaning of each broadcast.
The three consequence connection changes contain different meaning

I assume you only need connected/not connected 
So thats all u need

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {
        boolean noConnectivity = intent.getBooleanExtra(ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);

        if (noConnectivity) {
            //not_connnected statement    
        } else {
             //connected statement
    }
      }
}
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html
Dump EXTA_INFO of each broadcast, and you will find more info