# Checking for Internet connectivity on Android

Tags: android, internet-connection

I wrote the code below to check internet connection

```
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
    ConnectivityManager cm =
            (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetwork == null) {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (activeNetwork.isConnected()) {
          return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I've check if the activeNetWork is null, but still get NullPointerException error, why ?
[image]

Comment: have you added internet permission in your manifest file?

Comment: are you give permission in AndroidManifest file?

Comment: Exception message says that you tried to invoke method `isConnectedOrConnecting()` while in your code there is only `isConnected()` call. Are you sure that you are showing the right fragment of code?

Comment: Try this solution it wii work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37593058/checking-device-has-internet-connection/37593131#37593131@KevinWang

Comment: @lawstud, i've added the internet permission

Comment: @Rames, i tried both of the two methods, isConnectedOrConnecting() and isConnected, just not worked right

Comment: I use the same code,  and it's working now....so strange...

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
public static boolean isInternetconnected(Context ct) {  
   boolean connected = false;  
   //get the connectivity manager object to identify the network state.  
   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)ct.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);  
  //Check if the manager object is NULL, this check is required. to prevent crashes in few devices.
  if(connectivityManager != null) {  
     //Check Mobile data or Wifi net is present  

      if(connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||   
               connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)  {  
    //we are connected to a network  
    connected = true;  
     } else {  
      connected = false;  
   }  
  return connected;  
  } else  {  
  return false;  
 }  
}
```