# Option Menu Hide/Show-Android

Tags: android

I am working on an application that have use internet.

What i want to do if connection available than option menu showing if not than hide specific menu. & when internet available application show all menu item.

Comment: You need to implement Broadcast receiver
[Try this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. [removeItem](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Menu.html#removeItem(int))

You just have to pass an Id of your menu item that wants to hide. Add item again whenever you want.