# Get Network on android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

Tags: android, android-networking, bootcompleted, android-bootstrap

I've an app that has a receiver of `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and start a private VPN. But when I receive a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` the network isn't ready yet. What can I do to start a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED`and wait to have a network status? 
for example I can have a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` but the phone has no internet connection, or I can have a `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` and 5 seconds later a internet Access.

Comment: You must not wait in a broadcast receiver, but you may use one of the acceptable methods to schedule something to run a second or so later to check again, repeatedly.

Answer (score 3):

You could register a broadcast receiver listening on the android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE action.

then check if you are connected like this:

```
public boolean isOnline(Context context) {

ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
//should check null because in air plan mode it will be null
return (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected());

}
```

source and more information:
[Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Comment: "check if you are connected" isn't exactly what I'm lookinf for. If I'm inside the onBoot method triggered by BOOT_COMPLETED, i will wait the initial network boot and get the result of "have internet" or "not have internet" and continue with the correct method. If i only lookup con network change, i will wait until internet is active, so I can potentially wait infinite time until the internet will come. I just want a network ready-> internet yes/no -> do the right thing, because at BOOT_COMPLETED the 3g signal isn't ready.

Comment: then call isOnline() at BOOT_COMPLETED. if it is true do the stuff you want to do if internet is available. if it returns false, do the other stuff.

Comment: on boot_complete the network boot isn't setupped yet by the phone, so It mathematically choose the option isOnline's off.

Answer (score 3):

You can always listen to multiple items on one receiver:

```
<receiver android:name=".ReceiverName" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

So after boot you just wait for connectivity change and do your stuff.

Comment: "wait for connectivity change" isn't exactly what I'm lookinf for. If I'm inside the onBoot method triggered by BOOT_COMPLETED, i will wait the initial network boot and get the result of "have internet" or "not have internet" and continue with the correct method. If i only lookup con network change, i will wait until internet is active, so I can potentially wait infinite time until the internet will come. I just want a network ready-> internet yes/no -> do the right thing, because at BOOT_COMPLETED the 3g signal isn't ready.

Comment: Receiver will trigger 3 callbacks
on Boot
on ConnectivityChange and / or Wifi Stage Change ...
When you will receive onConnectivityChange - check if is online (snippet below) and thats it.