# open some link when my wifi connected in Android mobile

Tags: android, redirect, android-wifi, wifimanager, java-websocket

when wifi is connected in Andriod mobile,it should open playstore link automatically.We need open app-store in browser automatically.i.e We have 4 wifi's nets,itnet,poll,hotspot.We need When wifi connect nets after connected it's redirect to below link
[here](https://play.google.com/store?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

You can use BroadCastReceiver. Here some link how to implement BroadCastReceiver

[Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/

And When OnReceive() method call you can do your stuff.