# Broadcast Receiver OnReceive not called when checking internet connection after installation

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an app that has a BroadcastReceiver for checking internet connection. I installed the app then run it while I don't have internet connection but the OnReceive is not called. I kill the app then open it again but the OnReceive is still not called (tried this more than 10 times). So I turned on the internet then the OnReceive is called. I kill the app then turned off the internet again then run the app and it calls the OnReceive.

Question:
 - Why is this happening? (the part where I tried it more than 10 times)

Comment: any code? We are not wizzards :)

Comment: MainActivity - http://pastebin.com/KVPisCMM
Receiver - http://pastebin.com/iLEqzSfk

Comment: put your code inside your question, **plain text not URLs** please

Comment: you need to provide you manifest file too

Comment: Follow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app