# Sending data from local database to server

Tags: android

I have an app in which data gets stored in local database. All i want is to send this data to server whenever internet is connected and this process should be performed without starting app just like yahoo mail and watsapp.
Thnx in advance.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
public class Reciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

 if(isNetworkAvailable(context))
 {
    // Call your asynctask here for sending data to server.
 }
}

public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context context) {
        try{
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
            if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
                return true;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: srry my bad. ans aceptd.plz check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `BroadcastReceiver` that listens if the internet connection is available or not and if it's available it sends the saved data without starting the app.

Comment: can u give some example or link for reference

Comment: @IannHarper This is the broadcast link http://viralpatel.net/blogs/android-internet-connection-status-network-change/ but you'll need to write the code that sends the data to the server yourself

Answer (score 0):

1. You should learn how to user `Service` to send data to `Server` without open your app.
2. You should learn about `BroadcastReceiver` and use `ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION` to check internet connection status.