# How to manage network in android

Tags: android

I want to downloading image from instagram or picasa, during the downloading the network is disconnected. I want it should be start re downloading when the network connected again. downloading start from where the network was gone. 
plz give some idea or any reference link.

Thanks

Comment: There are many things, first download should be resume supported, second you need to check for internet connectivity in intervals and third doing the download process on the same file

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain can you give me any reference link.

Comment: There are no specific examples, you need to implement the logic yourself. But yes you can try the android guideline where [`Service`](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) do the same as you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

Register a broadcast for listening to network events. Please check [android network events](http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html).

This is already solved  in many other posts like [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)