# Alert dialog builder inside the if else statement - android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, dialog, android-alertdialog

I put Alert dialog builder inside my if else statement. Now, I want to do is to automatic dismiss the dialog in "if" statement and show the dialog in "else" statement. So, here is my codes.

```
 public void DisplayConn(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Error");
    builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    if(isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
        alert.dismiss();
    } else {
        alert.show();
    }
}
```

I don't want to use onClick button to dismiss the dialog, I just want to automatic dismiss the dialog in "if" statement. It is possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: public void DisplayConn(){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Error");
    builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false);
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    if(isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){

    } else {
        alert.show();
    }
} try this

Comment: yes it is possible just don't call show if condition is true

Comment: and remove dimiss call

Comment: Unnecessarily you are calling alert.dismiss(); in if part even though you have not actually shown the alert. You have just created it and not shown. Please remove that. Rest will work.  In any case if you want to dismiss your alert dialog, please put a check like 
if(alert!=null && alert.isShowing){
        alert.dismiss();
}

Comment: do you want your `Dialog` to be automatically destroyed when Internet is available?

Comment: @vrundpurohit Yes, i want dialog automatically destroyed when Internet is connected.

Comment: @saeed that is only show the dialog, i need is to show the dialog when the internet connection is lost and destroy the dialog automatic when the internet is connected again.

Comment: Ok now iam out of the desk be cool i will help you

Comment: @saeed okay. thaaanks.

Comment: try with Broadcast receiver  http://stackoverflow.com/a/26114247/3790150

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this:

```
public void DisplayConn(){
        if(!isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: ok, no issues let's put this topic to rest, please don't edit other's answer to make it same as other's answer already posted

Comment: The dialog is not destroy when I connect it again in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this...

```
   public void DisplayConn(){

        if(!isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Error");
        builder.setMessage("No Network Connection").setCancelable(false);
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

Comment: how it is different from my answer

Comment: @ankitagrawal..Dear I upvoted your answer... I think there is hardly 10 seconds difference in between yours and mine answer...I wrote the same answer from different way but Mr. Saeed changed my answer as you can see....

Comment: i was asking @saeed only , not you as i have already seen he edited your answer

Comment: @ankitagrawal If you are asking to saeed then please first of all mention his name....as i am seeing your profile you are a great person.... don;t do these foolish things... we are here to help someone not for gaining the points....

Comment: dear since i posted after his edit , I think it was obvious who i was asking , since your posted answer was different , it was your misunderstanding not my foolishness

Comment: The dialog is not gone when I connect it again in the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following

```
public void DisplayConn(){
    if(isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
        Pop.on(this).with().title("Error").cancelable(false).body("No Network Connection").show();
    }
}
```

after including this lib in your gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.vistrav:pop:2.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think `BroadcastReciver` will do the trick.

**try something like this.**

```
if(isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())){
    // do your work
} else {
    this.registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, new IntentFilter(
                    ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    alert.show();
}
```

And your `BroadcastReciver` would be as below.

```
private BroadcastReceiver mConnReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (isNetworkStatusAvailable(getApplicationContext())) {
            alert.dismiss();
        } else {
            // do nothing 
            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not Connected", 500)
            //      .show();
        }
    }
};
```

and final task.. you have to register this `BroadcastReciver` in `onResume` and unregister in `onPause`.

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    Your_class.this.unregisterReceiver(mConnReceiver);
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter(
            "packagename.classname");
    Your_class.this.registerReceiver(mConnReceiver, i);
}
```

I hope this will help you out.