# java.net.UnknownHostException error while using volley json android

Tags: android, json, android-volley, unknown-host

I am using Volley Json to connect my android app to web sever. It works fine at normal time. But when there is no connection while connecting the server, it toast "java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "www.example.com":No address associated with hostname". The app does not crush but as it show UnknownHostException error toast, it can probably annoy user. How can I hide that toast or handle that error. Please answer me.

Comment: post some code..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just comment out the toast statement inside

```
@Override
 public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
//Toast.makeToast(this,"toast",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
```

Comment: How can I recall the event while internet connection on?

Comment: use broadcast receiver when internet is connection is on. It will notify the activity then do your work that you want to do.

Comment: will you have any tutorial/Reference link for it?

Comment: check this answer and other answers in this threat http://stackoverflow.com/a/26114247/5275639

Comment: @ Zeeshan Shabbir : Thank you so much for your help. :) you deserve +1.

Comment: no problem. You can upvote the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening due to the internet connection error. If the internet connection is not there error listener get activated and it show the toast message. if you don't want that toast message just remove it in error listener.