# Activity won't load when checking internet connection

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to create an app that checks for internet connection when it opens. I want it to display a loading screen as long as there is not internet connection and a message. The loading screen activity is `activity_main.xml`. The problem is that because I'm calling `LoggingIn` method from itself, it keeps repeating it untill I have internet connection, but the problem is that for some reason it just won't load the activity itself. It just shows me a blank screen. When I don't run LoggingIn the activity does work.

Please help is there any other way to do this?

MainActivity.java:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LoggingIn();
}

public void LoggingIn ()
{
    if (isNetworkAvailable())
    {
        if (findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
        {
            findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        AttemptLoggingIn();
    }
    else
    {
        findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        LoggingIn();


    }
}
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager
            = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return activeNetworkInfo != null && activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
}
```

Comment: I encourage you to read [this](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html). You can use a callback instead of checking it in your way. Cheers

Comment: What the hell is this ??? Current checking?

Comment: @AugustoCarmo what do you mean use callback? I mean I still want to check for the internet connection constantly, how using callback will help me in this case? Thank you for your time!

Comment: Please, take a look at [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use background threads instead of your very strange method.

For example,

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    startCheck();
}


    private boolean startCheck() {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                          findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

        while(!isNetworkAvailable()) {

        try {
                                    Thread.sleep(100L);// 100 ms sleep
                                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
        }
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    findViewById(R.id.InternetConnection).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
                AttemptLoggingIn();
                    }
                });

        }
                    }).start();
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I still don't know what you did here but it fixed it! Now I'm gonna read what you did here :P

Comment: Lol. The idea is to start another thread which touches user interface only when the network is changed

Comment: So basically it keeps doing the loop in the middle as long as there is no internet connection, and when there is it continues to the rest of the code?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to call  LoggingIn() to monitor network changes.

ConnectivityManager automatically broadcasts the CONNECTIVITY_ACTION action whenever the connectivity details change.This article can be really useful for you:

http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/