# Autosync android app data when mobile connected to network

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have developed an application, which has a registration form. The data from registration form will be uploaded to **WebService** if candidates mobile is connected to the network. Else that data will be stored in local **MySQL** database.

What I want now is, when mobile is connected to a network, then the locally stored data should upload to WebService, even though he don't open that application. I am expecting functionality same as of WHATSAPP.

**Edited Solved**

Finally i found solution to this problem.Thank you so much everyone for participation.

```
package com.example.detapp;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class InternetConnector_Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        boolean isVisible;
        public static int flag1=0;
        public InternetConnector_Receiver() {

                                             }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            try {

                ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager
                            .getActiveNetworkInfo();

                    // Check internet connection and accrding to state change the
                    // text of activity by calling method
                    if ((networkInfo.isConnected()==true)) {
                        Log.i("*************DEEPA* insideif", "*********network : " +networkInfo.isConnected() );
                        flag1=1;
                        Toast.makeText(context, "*INTERNET CONNECTED*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        new MainActivity().Synchronization(flag1);


                    } else {
                        flag1=0;

                        Toast.makeText(context, "*NO INTERNET*", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        new MainActivity().Synchronization(flag1);
                    }

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

`

Added this broadcast receiver class InternetConnector_Receiver.java.This will work even when you are off to application.

And in MainActivity.java i added following code

```
protected void Synchronization(int flag)
    {
    if(flag==1)
    {
        //call webservice or sync Adapters here to synch data
    }
    }
```

Thank you all once again

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver if you are connected with net it will be run.

Comment: try this also<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app>.

Comment: Yeah my application have used broadcast receiver already.But broadcast received is limited to only my application,so data will be uploaded only when i open my application.It will not autosync as like WHATSAPP.

Comment: post your receiver code and menifest related to this.

Comment: See about sync adapter. It will help u. https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html

Comment: Simple you can use network broadcast receiver.

Comment: How can i set time duration for broadcast receiver?I mean i want to call it again after delay of 5minutes.Because it is calling often and not let me to complete my synchronization in that time of delay.

Comment: How to test your working code @DeepaMG? We tried it but no luck. When that Toast message displays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;


public class CustomBroadCastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isNetworkAvail(context)){
            //TODO:
        }
    }
    public boolean isNetworkAvail(Context mContext) {
        try {
            ConnectivityManager connectivity = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            if (connectivity != null) {
                NetworkInfo[] info = connectivity.getAllNetworkInfo();
                if (info != null)
                    for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                        if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED) {
                            return true;
                        }
            }
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ,Thanks for reply.But i used broadcast receiver already in my code.what should i do further to sync my data from local database to webserver automatically even when i am not using application?

Comment: do your webservice code inside the if(), it will work even if the app is not open..

Answer (score 0):

if your app needs to run in background,then create a broadcast reciever and  also specify the intent-filter and permission in manifest file.

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /><receiver android:name=".CustomBroadCastReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>`

Comment: I have used intent-filter and permission in my manifest file.I dint got what you mean by " then create a service and attach a broadcast reciever ".

Comment: I am very new to android.Please explain me about it clearly.please