# How to properly sync chat messages in offline/online mode?

Tags: android, messaging

Help me in designing a better solution to sync chat messages between a single app user and server. If an app goes offline, i want to store messages in app database and push them to server when internet is available. And if at same time someone sends user a message, i want to properly arrange them based on time stamps. But are time tamps reliable in this scenario?

Comment: You can check [SyncAdapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html)

Answer (score 1):

Yes timestamps are reliable. But make sure you dont update the timestamps when a message that was in pending queue is sent.

A way to look forward to this is creating a broadcast manager and since you already have an app-db things can be easy.

Step 1: Create a `BroadCastReceiver` to listen for network changes

A good SO post for the same can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app) where
`<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />` 
is used to detect connectivity changes.

Step 2: Create int flags for your messages:

Where: assume: int

0 -> unsent

1-> sent

2-> read etc...

So whenever the user sends the message, check for the internet connectivity using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238921/detect-whether-there-is-an-internet-connection-available-on-android) and if internet is not avail store to your app-local db with flag->`0` else post to server

if you get a positive callback from the server save it as flag->1 else again with 0.

Step 3: Now in your `onRecieve` method of your broadcast receiver, check if the changed status is a connected one (as in network connection is established) then pull from your db all messages which are saved with flag ->0 
and resend them to the server with again the validations checks in step 2: just make sure you update them this time instead of recreating a new entry!

And that should be it!

Comment: My pleasure. Do try it and let me know if it you need any further help. Also if it works do mark it as an answer so others may find it useful!