# How to Detect network disconnection in Firebase Job dispatcher?

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

In firebase Job dispatcher its possible to detect when we connect to a network, but how to detect when we disconnect from a network?

```
    Job myJob = dispatcher.newJobBuilder()
    .setService(MyJobService.class) 
    .setTag("my-unique-tag")
    .setConstraints(
    // only run on an unmetered network
    Constraint.ON_UNMETERED_NETWORK,
    // only run when the device is charging
    Constraint.DEVICE_CHARGING
     )
    .build();

dispatcher.mustSchedule(myJob);
```

This will detect when connected to Unmetrered Network , i want to start a service whenever it is disconnected from all networks

Answer (score 1):

Using firebase dispatcher you can't check the disconnection (As far as I know), but you can use broadcast receivers for detecting connectivity change and call your job service inside them

refer this link for the usage of broadcast receivers

[Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

in latest versions of android you need to dynamically register and unregister the Broadcast Receivers