# Perform a job using firebase job dispatcher only when there is no network available

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler, firebase-job-dispatcher

According to the [Constraint class](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android/blob/master/jobdispatcher/src/main/java/com/firebase/jobdispatcher/Constraint.java) of Firebase Job dispatcher, we can perform jobs when network is connected, or charging, etc.

How to perform a job when the internet is disconnected. Here is a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47044721/how-to-detect-network-disconnection-in-firebase-job-dispatcher) that went unanswered.

Comment: That's not a similar question, that's an exact duplicate. Please provide a use case for such feature, perhaps there is a better way than a job dispatcher.

Comment: What's a better way? Is it broadcast receiver? If yes, why?

Comment: When the network is gone, I want to change the display and I will also stop the mqtt service, and again start it, when the device finds a network. As far as I know use of network connectivity change broadcast is discouraged.

Comment: Check whether the internet is available inside the jobService and perform according to the availability

Comment: Remove the network constraint so that job can run even when there is no network.