# how you synchronized android app

Tags: android

When internet connection is on I want to send location parameter to server, and when internet off I want to save location parameter in realm database and after sometime when internet again on I want to send current location parameter to server and also send location parameter which saved in realm database to server which approach should I used.

Comment: you can use broadcast receiver for internet connectivity change for further reference you can go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26114247/5308778)

Comment: Please explain first what you have tried and where you stuck.

Comment: Where is your code? What you did? You want community to write your application code?

Comment: just listen to internet connection state changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a database and store those values there. Now after sending those value you must remove them from you database.

Now , create a broadcast class that always check the network status.When network comes it will check that db and send them on server. You can code it accordingly.

```
public class NetworkStatusChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    boolean status = Utility.isInternetAvailable(context);
    if (!status)
    {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Network Error !", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
 }
}
```

Put this in manifest.

```
   <receiver    
        android:name="NetworkStatusChangeReceiver"
        android:label="NetworkStatusChangeReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE" />
            <action android:name="android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

This might be helpful !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Follow this link to check internet connection [check network connection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32390749/4519859)

and if internet connection not found then store it to local database.

Comment: Referencing a link is not a answer.

Comment: @H.Brooks I already answered this question on this link, I don't want to duplicate answers to the same questions in different places.

Comment: Oh sorry about that, I didn't see your answer in that link.