# sendbroadcast method does not work when network is not available

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I have a function which I need to run when my app gets some data from remote server. `HTTPRequest` requires some time to execute, so when I get necessary data I send broadcast

```
Intent i = new Intent();
i.setAction(Receiver.BROADCAST_INITIALIZED);
activity.sendBroadcast(i);
```

My receiver:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

public static final String BROADCAST_INITIALIZED = "UNIQUE_ID";

public Receiver() {}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(BROADCAST_INITIALIZED)) {

        Log.i("TAG", "RECEIVER BROADCAST_INITIALIZED");

        context.unregisterReceiver(this);           
    }
}     
}
```

Everything works as expected until I disable mobile data and WiFi. In this case `activity.sendBroadcast(i);` does not trigger. I wonder why? 
I use simple function to check connection:

```
static boolean isNetworkAvailable(final Context context) {
    final ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = ((ConnectivityManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE));
    return connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
            && connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
}
```

and place it in timer (`timer.scheduleAtFixedRate`). When network is becoming available I execute HTTPRequest and get data after that I send broadcast and even then it doen't work!
Does `sendbroadcast` function work only when network is available?

**UPDATE** 
I found out the problem. It was my mistake. When I register my receivers I check network availability too and if it is not available I just skip registration.

```
if(!Utils.isNetworkAvailable(activity)) return; //The root of my problem!!!
    Receiver receiver = new Receiver(new Callable<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void call() throws Exception {                   
            func.call();
            return null;
        }
    });
    activity.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter(Receiver.BROADCAST_INITIALIZED));
```

Comment: You Should add Your Intent Filter to Regester your Receiver

Comment: you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/15700728/5773037 it ll be also Helps you

Comment: @NikunjParadva, The Intent filter starts the broadcast receiver when the connection changes. This is not suitable for me. I need to send the broadcast right after receiving the data from the server.

Comment: Which Method or Library You used for Sending Data To server?

Comment: @NikunjParadva, I use `HttpURLConnection`. It all works great until I disable network! The problem in `sendbroadcast` method.

Comment: put the send Brodcast Receiver Code to the success Callback
or you can use Retrofit 2 for Better CallBack. and use your Broadcast Receiver Their