# BroadcastReceiver to detect internet on background

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have a BroadcastReceiver that detects internet availablity changes. The code is working the app says online when internet is available and when I turn of WIFI or 4G it says offline. I have added this line of code to prevent the application from closing when back button is pressed:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }
```

When I press back button the application is put on background and the BroadcastReceiver says always offline even if internet is available. Why is it not working when app is put in background?

Thanks.

Code is below:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private NetworkReceiver receiver;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION);
        receiver = new NetworkReceiver();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        this.moveTaskToBack(true);
    }

}


public class NetworkReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(isConnected(context)) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Online", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Offline", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        boolean status = false;
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo activeNetwork = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        boolean isConnected = activeNetwork != null && activeNetwork.isConnectedOrConnecting();
        if (isConnected) {
            status = true;
        }
        return status;
    }

}

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.e.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Can anyone just copy the code and test it to see the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You have a dynamically registered `BroadcastReceiver`, when you move your app to background, this receiver is likely to be recycled by the Android system since this receiver is bound to the life cycle of your activity and the activity could very likely be recycled by Android since the activity is not supposed to run any background tasks. I suppose that's why even though sometimes you can still get broadcasts with this code, the stuff you are using inside returns false results because some of the components you are using are recycled by android already which results in the invalid result.

If you want to have a broadcast receiver that works in the background, register the broadcast receiver in the `AndroidManifest` with the corresponding intent filters and your implementation of a receiver service that will be fired once the broadcast is received.

Comment: Ok but isn't it depreciated to declare BroadcastReceivers in the manifest from Android 7.0 and up?

Comment: Where did you see that? I'm not aware of that at all. Are you referring to the restrictions on the broadcasts?

Comment: Look at the bottom of this page developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges also could you please suggest some code changes regarding your solution?

Comment: This doesn't mean all broadcast receivers in manifest are depreciated, this is what I mentioned about the restrictions on broadcasts. Basically Android doesn't want you to listen to network changes all the time now, which means there's nothing much you can do about it other than implementing some background mechanism and from there register a dynamic broadcast receiver to listen to the changes similar to the code in your question.