# Click on notification not launching the app

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

When push notification is received while the app is not running and the user presses on notification, it just disappears and the log says:

```
2019-10-22 12:42:45.747 23260-23260/de.app.test.staging E/FirebaseMessaging: Notification pending intent canceled
```

Here is the SplashActivity that is supposed to be launched as a Launcher Activity:

```
    <activity
        android:name="de.app.test.login.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

What can the issue be here?

Comment: Tried adding exported to true as you can see, but that didn't help.

Comment: share pending intent code

Comment: and is this issue only occuring on PIE. Or may be you haven't configure firebase messaging in manifest

Comment: Can't try on device below Pie right now, will see during the day.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For anyone looking for an answer, the back-end was sending the "click_action" to notification, therefore there was no intent filter for that Activity.

For me the click_action is "OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" so I just added one more intent-filter to my SplashActivity like this:

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="OPEN_ACTIVITY_1" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forground app:

You need a PendingIntent to open app.

Try this:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
        .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, SplashActivity.class);

notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
        notificationIntent, 0);

notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

If Activity is in background or closed then notification message is shown in the notification center for app launcher activity.

You can use a BroadcastReceiver class. When you close the app, broadcast can listen this action. So, if you create a BroadcastReceiver class, you don't take this problem.

```
public class ClosedBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, HomePage.class));
        } else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, HomePage.class));
        }
    }
}
```

More Information:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/receive

Comment: That's when the app is in foreground, that works. The issue is while the app is in background (no process running).

Comment: You are right. The answer is edited. @SavaDimitrijević

Comment: Thank you for answering, however that is the issue. The launcher activity is not launching at all, and the log says "Notification pending intent canceled"

Comment: Where would I register this broadcast and why is it only if  the device is above Oreo?

Comment: Please refer to this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app/44881551#44881551

Comment: I understand the principle of BroadcastReceiver , but since the app is not launching at all upon notification click, this cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

you need to set pendingIntent object in notificationBuilder instance like

```
 mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, TargetActivity.class));
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
```

Please note that CHANNEL_ID is for build version greater or equal to Oreo

```
   if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        CHANNEL_ID = createNotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, "channelName");
    }


  @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
private String createNotificationChannel(String channelId, String channelName) {
    // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
    // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library

    String description = "description";

    NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
    channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
    channel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
    channel.setDescription(description);
    // Register the channel with the system; you can't change the importance
    // or other notification behaviors after this
    mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    return channelId;

}
```

Comment: That's when the app is in foreground, that works. The issue is while the app is in background (no process running).