# Update content in the Recycler View without reloading activity

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit, retrofit2, rx-java2

I need that when connected to the Internet, my list is updated and pulls up fresh information from the resource on the API, but I do not know how to do it. Maybe someone has encountered this problem or maybe has a solution to this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should detect the internet connection
[Broadcast receiver for checking internet connection in android app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15698790/broadcast-receiver-for-checking-internet-connection-in-android-app)

then when in onReceive() callback, request your data from API and update your recyclerview